# SSO with ADFS 2.0 using Identity and Access in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

We are trying to develop a SSO sample application with ADFS 2.0 using Visual Studio 2012, while searching we able to find SSO & ADFS 2.0 & external application, and more explanations with Visual Studio 2010 only.

As per our requirement we need to use SSO with ADFS 2.0 and our application alone.
We followed a link [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide%28WS.10%29.aspx)
But here they are using Visual Studio 2010, but followed that site and we developed using Visual Studio 2012, all went fine, at last we got error with dlls. We can't able to use SecurityToken with latest dll.

Can anyone help us

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific on what errors you are getting...
Next to that have you tried compiling your VS2012 solution against the .NET Framework 4.0 (which would be the only difference from for programming in VS2010)

Comment: We followed the above link and we completed the configuration, so while running the application it is getting the claims, but while invoking the wcf from there, we are getting NullPointer Exception on SecurityToken receiving part

Answer (score 0):

That link talks about using the FedUtil tool (VS2010). Did you use the "Identity and Access Tool" (VS2012) ?

- [Windows Identity Foundation Tools for Visual Studio 2012 RTM](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/10/23/windows-identity-foundation-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-rtm-2/)
- [A Refresh of the Identity and Access Tool for VS 2012](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/03/25/a-refresh-of-the-identity-and-access-tool-for-vs-2012/)

Samples (VS 2012) to act as a guide here:

[Windows Identity Foundation in the .NET Framework 4.5 Beta: Tools, Samples, Claims Everywhere](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/03/15/windows-identity-foundation-in-the-net-framework-4-5-beta-tools-samples-claims-everywhere-2/)